# Git sparse checkout: adding directories to existing list is not recognized

Tags: git, gitlab, sparse-checkout

### Situation

I managed to create a local git repository in my laptop by pulling a single subdirectory of the master branch in a remote repository. I have followed the instructions given in this post on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/5459638. I use git version 2.22.0.

The path of the subdirectory, with respect to `https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>/tree/master` as given in the project web page, is contained in the file `.git/info/sparse-checkout`, say

```
subdir1/subdir11/
```

The command

```
git pull mylaptop master
```

does create a local copy of the intended directories. This is confirmed with a `tree -d`. `mylaptop` was a name of choice for the local repository. This worked fine.

### Issue

I then wanted to fetch a sibling directory and its child from the same remote too, say

```
subdir1/subdir12/
```

I added this path as a new line in the sparse-checkout file and run the git pull command above. However, the outcome is

```
From https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

and I see no change in the local tree.

### Research

Out of several suggestions I came across in Stackoverflow, I gave it a try to `git update-index --skip-worktree`, but to no avail. I did this out of intution and would avoid blind trials though. It is not a question of trailing slashes in the paths either.

### Question

Apparently I am missing something that makes Git realize that the list has been extended. What could this be?

Comment: Try `git checkout`.

Comment: @ElpieKay When? That is, after and before what?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the new path to `.git/info/sparse-checkout` do

```
git checkout master
```

Thus, you do this instead of the initial `git pull` command.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to merge and update the files in the work tree.

**Simply run:**

`git read-tree -mu HEAD`

More information: [git-read-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree)